# IOS. Whats the difference between these 2 commands

Tags: vlan, cisco-ios, trunk

I am completing an online course for the network+ and am going through one of the labs. Here is a diagram of the network in question.
 [image]

Specifically I have a switch with 24 fast ethernet ports and 2gigabit ports and the tasks mentioned are to do the following:

- Manually designate ports fa0/8, fa0/23-24, gi0/1-2 as trunk ports.
- For each trunk port remove the current vlan assignment
- Manually configure the remaining ports as access ports.
- save the changes in the startup config file.

To achieve this I entered the following commands:

```
en 
conf t. 
int range fa0/8, fa0/23-24, gi0/1-2
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 2-4094
end 
conf t 
int range fa0/1-7, fa0/9-22
switchport mode access 
end 
copy run start
```

The solution calls for using the code

```
no switchport access vlan
```

instead of:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 2-4094
```

What is the difference(if any) between these 2 commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**no switchport access vlan** is used to reset the access-mode VLAN to the appropriate default VLAN for the switch. This default vlan can be defined by the administrator to be any value(which means it could be other than 1). Keep in mind that the concept of 802.1q tagging makes no sense for an access port.

**switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 2-4094** allows traffic from vlan 1 ONLY to be sent across the link as tagged*(if vlan 1 is not native vlan) or untagged.

*Tagging:  adding an identifier to frames to indicate what VLAN the frame belongs to

Answer (score 3):

The instructions are ambiguous. Once the port is configured as a trunk, any access configuration statements are meaningless. If they want you to remove the now vestigial access mode configuration, *that's what they should ask you to do.* I would recommend getting in the habit of removing the access mode configuration(s) for trunk ports as a "Best Practice" to avoid any confusion and/or issues in the future.

"*no switchport access vlan*" simply returns the port's access vlan to the switch default. (usually "1") "*switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 2-4094*" removes all vlans from the trunk port. If the switch default vlan is not "1", the port will carry no traffic. Note, VLAN 1 *cannot* be removed from the port (or tagged) because of various link-layer protocols like spanning-tree. You can specify some other vlan to be the native (untagged) vlan, but "1" still cannot be removed. (I've always found that a rather annoying Cisco-ism.)

Answer (score 0):

Access ports and trunk ports are two types of vlan passing technic on switching

Access ports carries single Vlan traffic . Access port are enable on switchports where end devices are connected .

Switch (config)#int f0/1
Switch(config)Switchport mode access
Switch(config)#switchport access vlan 10
Switch(config)no shutdown

**To disable access vlan Access use this command**

`Switch (config)#no switch access vlan 10`

**This above command disables single Vlan traffic on specific link**

**Trunk port**

Configuring Switchport with trunk port enables to pass multiple VLANs trunk ports can be configured in between router to switches , switches to base servers

Switch(config)#int F0/1
Switch(config)#switchport mode trunk
Switch(config)#switchport trunk allowed vlans all
Switch(config)#no shutdown.

**To disable trunkport configuration**

`Switch(config)#no switch trunk allowed vlans 10`

This command will remove vlan10 traffic from trunk link

`Switch (config)# no Switchport trunk allowed vlan all`

This command stops multiple VLANs traffic fron trunk link